# How do I make the second and third pyramid

Tags: python

[image]

I completed part A and Part B but im stuck on part C.

> ```
> print("Pattern C:")
> for rowc in range(1, 7):
>     for column in range(1, rowc + 1):
>         print(column, end=' ')      
>     print("")
> ```
>
> That is all I have for part C right now which is essentially just part A.

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply strings with an integer, e.g.`print("foo"*3)` outputs  `"foofoofoo"`. You can use this concept to multiply a string consisting of a single space with an integer:

```
print("Pattern C:")
    for i in range(1, 7):
        rowString = " "*7-i
        for j in range(1,i):
            rowString += str(j)
        print(rowString)
```